# Accumulate selection results in the list(not table) in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I just started MVC and would appreciate help in solving problem. I have a group of manufacturer were  I’m selecting a group of products  for particular manufacturer and taking some of them. After that I repeat then same procedure for another manufacturer and so on. Now the question. How I can accumulate chosen products in one list (not in table) for future processing.

Comment: Please post your code to fix it out.

Comment: Where is your code? Where have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Your product model can be like this:

```
public int ProductId { set; get; }
public string Code { set; get; }
public string Name { set; get; }
public int ManufacturerId { set; get; }
public virtual Manufacrer Manufacrer { set; get; }
```

Your product controller can have some action like this: (using a show button though in the view though, without using jquery)

```
public ViewResult ViewProductStatus(int? manufacturerId)
    {
        ViewBag.ManufacturerId = new SelectList(db.Manufacturers, "ManufacturerId", "Code");
        if (Manufacturer != null)
        {
            return View(db.Products.Include(c => c.Manufacturer).Where(c => c.Manufacturers.ManufacturerId == manufacturerId));
        }
        else
        {
            return View(db.Products.Include(c => c.Manufacturers));
        }
    }
```

Create a view under Product View, name it ViewProduct and Your ViewProduct can be like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Appname.Models.Product>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View Product";
}

<h2>View Product</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownList("manufacturerId", String.Empty)
    <input type="submit" value="Show" />
}

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

    <div>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Code)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>



@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
    </div>
    <div>    
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </div>    

    </div>
}
```